# how do i make vertical text fill full page height without adding space

Tags: html, css

i have been stuck with this problem for days now and can't solve it
basically i have a page with vertical text in a div that has these properties :

```css
.sideText {            
    white-space: nowrap;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    position: absolute;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    left: 0;
}
```

it is a very long text (whole paragraph)

what i am trying to achieve is that this text takes the entire height of page (this div is the first tag inside body)

when i try to give it :

```
height: 100%;
```

it takes the height of the viewport and stops right after
any suggestion on how i can do this ?
thank you all

Edit: adding reproducible page

```css
        .sideText {            
            white-space: nowrap;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            position: absolute;
            color: var(--primary-color);
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="sideText" class="fs-1 fw-bold sideText">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget malesuada mi, tempus posuere elit. Donec eget massa a orci ultrices facilisis at id velit. Duis in purus diam. Phasellus tortor sem, porta a augue ac, porttitor ultricies quam. In metus mi, volutpat eu urna quis, consequat tristique velit. Suspendisse malesuada blandit arcu, in malesuada dui pulvinar non. Fusce ullamcorper, nibh sit amet tempor ullamcorper, mauris mauris aliquam nunc, eu aliquet ipsum velit eget leo. Nam varius pulvinar condimentum. Sed egestas libero vel lacus placerat mollis. Nullam vehicula sollicitudin dui. Proin vel accumsan arcu. Vestibulum in risus vehicula, eleifend enim at, lobortis elit. Fusce aliquam efficitur sapien, nec cursus urna tincidunt eget.
    </div>
    <div style="margin:10px;">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget malesuada mi, tempus posuere elit. Donec eget massa a orci ultrices facilisis at id velit. Duis in purus diam. Phasellus tortor sem, porta a augue ac, porttitor ultricies quam. In metus mi, volutpat eu urna quis, consequat tristique velit. Suspendisse malesuada blandit arcu, in malesuada dui pulvinar non. Fusce ullamcorper, nibh sit amet tempor ullamcorper, mauris mauris aliquam nunc, eu aliquet ipsum velit eget leo. Nam varius pulvinar condimentum. Sed egestas libero vel lacus placerat mollis. Nullam vehicula sollicitudin dui. Proin vel accumsan arcu. Vestibulum in risus vehicula, eleifend enim at, lobortis elit. Fusce aliquam efficitur sapien, nec cursus urna tincidunt eget.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post reproducible  html and css code.

Comment: @TheDuo done, thank you for tazking time for this

Comment: If I am understanding correctly, you want the text to be the height of the window. Is that right? If you remove `white-space: nowrap;`, is that the behavior you are looking for?

Comment: The content of the normal text must meet or exceed the height (width depending on perspective?) of the vertical text or vice versa.

Comment: can do that using js , is that okey with you?

Comment: @chase the `code`white-space: nowrap;`code` must be there because i don't want the vertical text to go back to line break

Comment: @zer00ne the point is that the vertical text should stop at min height of 100vh or the height of the normal text

Comment: @TheDuo to be honest i would take any solutoin at this point!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this line of JavaScript, to archive what you want:

```js
document.getElementById("sideText").style.height = document.body.clientHeight + "px";
```

```css
.sideText {            
    white-space: nowrap;
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    position: absolute;
    color: var(--primary-color);
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="sideText" class="fs-1 fw-bold sideText">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget malesuada mi, tempus posuere elit. Donec eget massa a orci ultrices facilisis at id velit. Duis in purus diam. Phasellus tortor sem, porta a augue ac, porttitor ultricies quam. In metus mi, volutpat eu urna quis, consequat tristique velit. Suspendisse malesuada blandit arcu, in malesuada dui pulvinar non. Fusce ullamcorper, nibh sit amet tempor ullamcorper, mauris mauris aliquam nunc, eu aliquet ipsum velit eget leo. Nam varius pulvinar condimentum. Sed egestas libero vel lacus placerat mollis. Nullam vehicula sollicitudin dui. Proin vel accumsan arcu. Vestibulum in risus vehicula, eleifend enim at, lobortis elit. Fusce aliquam efficitur sapien, nec cursus urna tincidunt eget.
    </div>
    <div style="margin:10px;">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget malesuada mi, tempus posuere elit. Donec eget massa a orci ultrices facilisis at id velit. Duis in purus diam. Phasellus tortor sem, porta a augue ac, porttitor ultricies quam. In metus mi, volutpat eu urna quis, consequat tristique velit. Suspendisse malesuada blandit arcu, in malesuada dui pulvinar non. Fusce ullamcorper, nibh sit amet tempor ullamcorper, mauris mauris aliquam nunc, eu aliquet ipsum velit eget leo. Nam varius pulvinar condimentum. Sed egestas libero vel lacus placerat mollis. Nullam vehicula sollicitudin dui. Proin vel accumsan arcu. Vestibulum in risus vehicula, eleifend enim at, lobortis elit. Fusce aliquam efficitur sapien, nec cursus urna tincidunt eget.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

her you go .

i choose to increase `font-size` and `line-height` you  can choose whatever you seem fit for your requirments,

```js
var $div = $('.main-text');

$(window).resize(function () {
   // Get the current height of the div and save it as a variable.
   var height = $div.height();
   // Set the font-size and line-height of the text within the div according to the current height.
   $div.css({
      'font-size': (height/2) + 'px',
      'line-height': height + 'px'
   })
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
.sideText {            
            white-space: nowrap;
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            position: absolute;
            color: var(--primary-color);
            left: 0;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<body>
  <div id="sideText" class="fs-1 fw-bold sideText">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget malesuada mi, tempus posuere elit. Donec eget massa a orci ultrices facilisis at id velit. Duis in purus diam. Phasellus tortor sem, porta a augue ac, porttitor ultricies quam. In metus mi, volutpat eu urna quis, consequat tristique velit. Suspendisse malesuada blandit arcu, in malesuada dui pulvinar non. Fusce ullamcorper, nibh sit amet tempor ullamcorper, mauris mauris aliquam nunc, eu aliquet ipsum velit eget leo. Nam varius pulvinar condimentum. Sed egestas libero vel lacus placerat mollis. Nullam vehicula sollicitudin dui. Proin vel accumsan arcu. Vestibulum in risus vehicula, eleifend enim at, lobortis elit. Fusce aliquam efficitur sapien, nec cursus urna tincidunt eget.
    </div>
    <div class="main-text" style="margin:10px;">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam eget malesuada mi, tempus posuere elit. Donec eget massa a orci ultrices facilisis at id velit. Duis in purus diam. Phasellus tortor sem, porta a augue ac, porttitor ultricies quam. In metus mi, volutpat eu urna quis, consequat tristique velit. Suspendisse malesuada blandit arcu, in malesuada dui pulvinar non. Fusce ullamcorper, nibh sit amet tempor ullamcorper, mauris mauris aliquam nunc, eu aliquet ipsum velit eget leo. Nam varius pulvinar condimentum. Sed egestas libero vel lacus placerat mollis. Nullam vehicula sollicitudin dui. Proin vel accumsan arcu. Vestibulum in risus vehicula, eleifend enim at, lobortis elit. Fusce aliquam efficitur sapien, nec cursus urna tincidunt eget.
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```